# FDT: variables panel doestn inspect display objects properly

Tags: fdt

Im having problems with the Variables panel in FDT. Every MovieClip in the list shows just "blendShader" property. However, if i mark it to "Watch", go to Watch panel and write there those properties, FDT can shows the value like "width", "height", "name" and "stage".

The variables panel should not shown those properties/values when i click the arrow to "open" all properties?

It turns the debugging really difficult, because all clips I need to do a "Watch" and type the property manually in the panel just to trace out its values.

Here how I see the MovieClip properties in Variables panel:
http://clientes.ppalmeida.com.br/dev/fdt_1.png

Here how I see the Watch panel: other properties of the movieClip can be "evaluated":
http://clientes.ppalmeida.com.br/dev/fdt_2.png

Now, check that, even in Watch panel, if I click the arrow to "open" other properties of the MovieClip (first line, "this._target", it shows up just "blendShader" property:
http://clientes.ppalmeida.com.br/dev/fdt_3.png

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it.

In the Variables panel there is a little down arrow on top right. It opens up a pop-up baloon. I've choose all options to as3 and all informations I want are now available.

Hope it helps someone.

[image]

1) Click the little arrow; 
2) Point over "as3"; 
3) Mark the desirable options

Cheers.